# What is the difference between “mandatory fair compensation” and “license” in EU copyright law?

Tags: copyright, european-union

I have been reading laws about exceptions to copyright in the EU. Article 5 of the CDSM, for example, talks about licenses and about fair compensation to right holders. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: You've quoted "mandatory fair compensation" in your title, but I can't find that phrase in the CDSM. Also licences and compensation are fairly different words with very different meanings, is there anything specific you don't understand about them?

Comment: Actually, I was reading this comment two the Article https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3432311. I was confused by the sentence “ Even if the exception were subject to mandatory fair compensation”. Is that the same as a license?